# Bulk Image Upload And Rerrange Functionality

Tags: plugins, images, uploads

I am looking for a solution, it can be pre-existing plugin or code I put into my functions.php file that will allow me to batch upload images to a post, and then have the ability to rearrange the positioning of them.

I know Wordpress by default allows you to batch upload images, so I am presuming the solution will use that functionality. But to my knowledge it doesn't let you adjust the order of which they are attached to the post.

The reason I need to be able to have the option of rearranging bulk-uploaded images, is because on the front-end, images are shown sort of like a mosaic where multiple images make up one larger image in the form of  grid.

**The scenario**:

- A user creates a new post.
- A user then clicks on a button which shows the media uploader and allows them to upload a whole bunch of images at once.
- The images are processed and then associated with the post.
- The user is then able to rearrange the order of the attached post images which will then be displayed in that particular order on the homepage in a WP post loop.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gallery tab allows you to order images by default.

Click *Add Image* --->*Gallery* You can then number the photos in the little boxes.

---

[image]

**They can then be sorted in ascending/descending/date/time/random**

---

[image]

Comment: Aww man, I feel so stupid right now. I knew you could enter values to re-order but never knew you could also drag and re-arrange them, hahaha. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As above but also you can reorder the images by clicking on  there name. The mouse turns into the cross with arrows. Saving the order and the images will be in a specific order.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out you can drag to re-order, I never knew you could do that. I've given you an upvote.